# html_entity_decode and HTML <textarea> tag

Tags: php, html, html-entities, html-encode

I am using html_entity_decode to display proper html when retrieved from the database.
So suppose i have

```
$data = '<b> Hello </b>'
$data = html_entity_decode($data);
```

// outputs **Hello**  but when I do

```
<textarea><?=$data?></textarea>
```

The value in textarea is appearing as it is ie :

```
<b> Hello </b>
```

WHy so ?

Comment: There are no encoded html entities in your original string, so `html_entity_decode()` does nothing. Are you looking for `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Because a textarea can have only _text_ content …?

Comment: @jeroen -> When i inserted it into the textarea i did htmlentities($data) so decode shouls work right ?

Comment: @CBroe -> So is there no way to output html formatted data in a textarea ?

Comment: Of course there isn’t. (And if your next question is, _“but then how do sites like f.e. Facebook do this?”_, the answer is that you want to research “contenteditable”.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when you inserted the data inside the database, it wasn't encoded. Unless its encoded, Decode doesn't work.

Plus, the main scenario is, textarea can contain text element only. When you put that data inside `<textarea><?=$data?></textarea>`, you are actually putting `<b> Hello </b>`. So Text area purse it as plain text. You can understand more about this via [W3C text area standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7).

Comment: When i inserted into the database, i did htmlentities($data). So while retrieving html_entity_decode should probably work right ? So is there anyway to decode html elements and output in textarea or textarea can only always output plain text only ?

Comment: Textarea can output plain text only.